# Question on tangent circles

Tags: geometry

Prove that two circles C1 and C2 (rays are R1 and R2 respectively, centers O1 and O2 respectively, and R1>R2) are tangent to each other (interior tangent, so C2 inside C1) if and only if O1O2=R1-R2 .

I was able to prove this analytically, using the equation of the circle, but I want to know a sinthetic proof, easy to understand. Thank you!

Comment: They can also be tangent if $O1O2=R1+R2$.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be point of tangency. Now, $O_1$ , $P$ and $O_2$ are collinear (as $O_1 P$ and $O_2P$ are perpendicular to same line, the tangent at $P$). Also, $O_2$ is between $O_1$ and $P$, because $C_2$ is smaller circle. Therefore, $$O_1O_2=O_1P-O_2P=R_1-R_2$$

Conversely, if the distance between centres is this, then the farthest point on $C_2$ from $O_1$ is $O_1O_2+R_2=R_1$ away. Hence, this point is point of tangency.

Hope it helps:)